# Error with pkg: /data/local/tmp/... Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

Tags: java, android

I want to run my project in a virtual device but I got the error below. Before it occurred this time, I was never facing this error.

What's does this error exactly mean and what is the root cause for it? Is there any suggestion to how fix it?

```
error with pkg: /data/local/tmp/"my package name" 
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```